# is there any difference between test {useJUnitPlatform()} and tasks.withType(Test) {useJUnitPlatform()}

Tags: java, gradle, junit

Is there any difference between specifying in `build.gradle`

```
test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping) the first one is groovy (`build.gradle`) and the second one is kotlin (`build.gradle.kts`).